# Oculus 0.8 SDK Black Screen

Tags: opengl, oculus

I'm trying to make a very basic example of rendering to the Oculus using their SDK v0.8. All I'm trying to do is render a solid color to both eyes. When I run this, everything appears to initialize correctly. The Oculus shows the health warning message, but all I see is a black screen once the health warning message goes away. What am I doing wrong here?

```
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <GL/glew.h>
#define OVR_OS_WIN32
#include <OVR_CAPI_GL.h>
#include <SDL.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);   
    SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow("OpenGL", 100, 100, 800, 600, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);
    SDL_GLContext context = SDL_GL_CreateContext(window);

    //Initialize GLEW
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    glewInit();

    // Initialize Oculus context
    ovrResult result = ovr_Initialize(nullptr);
    if (OVR_FAILURE(result))
    {
        std::cout << "ERROR: Failed to initialize libOVR" << std::endl;
        SDL_Quit();
        return -1;
    }

    // Connect to the Oculus headset
    ovrSession hmd;
    ovrGraphicsLuid luid;
    result = ovr_Create(&hmd, &luid);
    if (OVR_FAILURE(result))
    {
        std::cout << "ERROR: Oculus Rift not detected" << std::endl;
        SDL_Quit();
        return 0;
    }

    ovrHmdDesc desc = ovr_GetHmdDesc(hmd);

    std::cout << "Found " << desc.ProductName << "connected Rift device" << std::endl;

    ovrSizei recommenedTex0Size = ovr_GetFovTextureSize(hmd, ovrEyeType(0), desc.DefaultEyeFov[0], 1.0f);
    ovrSizei bufferSize;
    bufferSize.w = recommenedTex0Size.w;
    bufferSize.h = recommenedTex0Size.h;

    std::cout << "Buffer Size: " << bufferSize.w << ", " << bufferSize.h << std::endl;

    // Generate FBO for oculus
    GLuint oculusFbo = 0;
    glGenFramebuffers(1, &oculusFbo);

    // Create swap texture
    ovrSwapTextureSet* pTextureSet = nullptr;
    if (ovr_CreateSwapTextureSetGL(hmd, GL_SRGB8_ALPHA8, bufferSize.w, bufferSize.h,&pTextureSet) == ovrSuccess)
    {
        ovrGLTexture* tex = (ovrGLTexture*)&pTextureSet->Textures[0];
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex->OGL.TexId);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    }


    // Create ovrLayerHeader

    ovrEyeRenderDesc eyeRenderDesc[2];
    eyeRenderDesc[0] = ovr_GetRenderDesc(hmd, ovrEye_Left, desc.DefaultEyeFov[0]);
    eyeRenderDesc[1] = ovr_GetRenderDesc(hmd, ovrEye_Right, desc.DefaultEyeFov[1]);

    ovrLayerEyeFov layer;

    layer.Header.Type = ovrLayerType_EyeFov;
    layer.Header.Flags = ovrLayerFlag_TextureOriginAtBottomLeft | ovrLayerFlag_HeadLocked;
    layer.ColorTexture[0] = pTextureSet;
    layer.ColorTexture[1] = pTextureSet;
    layer.Fov[0] = eyeRenderDesc[0].Fov;
    layer.Fov[1] = eyeRenderDesc[1].Fov;

    ovrVector2i posVec;
    posVec.x = 0;
    posVec.y = 0;

    ovrSizei sizeVec;
    sizeVec.w = bufferSize.w;
    sizeVec.h = bufferSize.h;

    ovrRecti rec;
    rec.Pos = posVec;
    rec.Size = sizeVec;

    layer.Viewport[0] = rec;
    layer.Viewport[1] = rec;

    ovrLayerHeader* layers = &layer.Header;


    SDL_Event windowEvent;
    while (true)
    {
        if (SDL_PollEvent(&windowEvent))
        {
            if (windowEvent.type == SDL_QUIT) break;
        }
        ovrGLTexture* tex = (ovrGLTexture*)&pTextureSet->Textures[0];
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, oculusFbo);
        glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex->OGL.TexId, 0);
        glViewport(0, 0, bufferSize.w, bufferSize.h);
        glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        ovr_SubmitFrame(hmd, 0, nullptr, &layers, 1);

        SDL_GL_SwapWindow(window);
    }

    SDL_GL_DeleteContext(context);
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: After some additional testing, I think it has to do with my use of ovrLayerEyeFov. Using the direct layer type (ovrLayerDirect) lets me see the texture on the oculus.

Comment: ovrLayerDirect basically just blits your texture to the screen without any distortion.  It might work for you now, but it will be virtually useless going forward.  It's primarily a tool for testing output to the display and lens distortion stuff... once you move past rendering a solid color it won't help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of problems here

- Not initializing `ovrLayerEyeFov.RenderPose`
- Not using `ovrSwapTextureSet` correctly
- Useless calls to `SDL_GL_SwapWindow` will cause stuttering
- Possible undefined behavior when reading the texture while it's still bound for drawing

**Not initializing `ovrLayerEyeFov.RenderPose`**

You main problem is that you're not setting the `RenderPose` member of the `ovrLayerEyeFov` structure.  This member tells the SDK what pose you rendered at and therefore how it should apply timewarp based on the current head pose (which might have changed since you rendered).  By not setting this value you're basically giving the SDK a random head pose, which is almost certainly not a valid head pose.

Additionally, `ovrLayerFlag_HeadLocked` isn't needed for your layer type.  It causes the Oculus to display the resulting image in a fixed position relative to your head.  It might do what you want, but *only* if you properly initialize the `layer.RenderPose` members with the correct values (I'm not sure what those would be in the case of `ovrLayerEyeFov`, as I've only used the flag in combination with `ovrLayerQuad`).

What you should do is add the following right after the layer declaration to properly initialize it:

```
memset(&layer, 0, sizeof(ovrLayerEyeFov));
```

Then, inside your render loop you should add the following right after the check for a quit event:

```
ovrTrackingState tracking = ovr_GetTrackingState(hmd, 0, true);
layer.RenderPose[0] = tracking.HeadPose.ThePose;
layer.RenderPose[1] = tracking.HeadPose.ThePose;
```

This tells the SDK that this image was rendered from the point of view where the head currently is.

**Not using `ovrSwapTextureSet` correctly**

Another problem in the code is that you're incorrectly using the texture set.  The documentation specifies that when using the texture set, you need to use the texture pointed to by `ovrSwapTextureSet.CurrentIndex`:

```
ovrGLTexture* tex = (ovrGLTexture*)(&(pTextureSet->Textures[pTextureSet->CurrentIndex]));
```

...and then after each call to `ovr_SubmitFrame` you need to increment `ovrSwapTextureSet.CurrentIndex`  then mod the value by `ovrSwapTextureSet.TextureCount` like so

```
pTextureSet->CurrentIndex = (pTextureSet->CurrentIndex + 1) % pTextureSet->TextureCount;
```

**Useless calls to `SDL_GL_SwapWindow` will cause stuttering**

The `SDL_GL_SwapWindow(window);` call is unnecessary and pointless since you haven't drawn anything to the default framebuffer.  Once you move away from drawing a solid color, this call will end up causing judder, since it will block until v-sync (typically at 60hz) causing you to sometimes miss the refersh of the Oculus display.  Right now this will be invisible because your *scene* is just a solid color, but later on when you're rendering objects in 3D, it will cause intolerable judder.

You *can* use `SDL_GL_SwapWindow` if you

- Ensure v-sync is disabled
- Have a mirror texture available to draw to the window.  (See the documentation for `ovr_CreateMirrorTextureGL`)

**Possible framebuffer issues**

I'm less certain about this one being a serious problem, but I would also suggest unbinding the framebuffer and detaching the Oculus provided texture *before* sending it to `ovr_SubmitFrame()`, as I'm not certain that the behavior is well defined when reading from a texture attached to a framebuffer that is currently bound for drawing. It seems to have no impact on my local system, but undefined doesn't mean *doesn't work*, it just means you can't rely on it to work.

I've updated the sample code and put it [here](https://gist.github.com/jherico/cbf5aaa7a679f739fff2).  As a bonus I've modified it so it draws one color on the left eye and a different color on the right eye, as well as setting up the buffer to provide for rendering one half of the buffer for each eye.

Comment: Wow, this was more than I was expecting someone to provide. Thanks a ton for the help!

Comment: Not initializing ovrLayerEyeFov.RenderPose and not using ovrSwapTextureSet correctly were definitely the problem. Finally, I got the "hello world" opengl triangle to appear on the oculus :) Thanks again.